# Does ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed method wait for vertex and pixel shader opertions to be completed?

Tags: c++, directx-11, hlsl

I am using vertex and pixel shaders to perform basic operations such as matrix multiplication in vertex shaders and Texture sampling using pixel shader. I was wondering in the below statements , does the last statement wait till the vertex and pixel shader operations are performed.

```
deviceContext->VSSetShader(VS, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->PSSetShader(PS, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &Sampler);
deviceContext->DrawIndexed(IndexCount, 0, 0); // Does it wait for pixel operations to be performed on all pixels?
```

Comment: Your question is both interesting and too broad. Do you have evidence this occurs in parallel instead of sequentially? On which video chips and drivers? How does that impact your project?

Comment: I have no issues with this in my project but was trying to make sure after the DrawIndexed() call returns all the pixel operations are performed in shaders which are performed in GPU. In other words, is there a way the GPU interacts with CPU - host about its completion. (Could not find any info  on this in documentation). Trying to assert that after this call returns and scene is presented using IDXGISwapChain::Present method all the pixel operations on each pixel is always done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3D, work is executed on the GPU in the order it is submitted, but in general it is not synchronized with the CPU. In your code for example, by the time `DrawIndexed` returns on the CPU, the GPU will very likely not have even begun rendering yet. Often tens of thousands of commands are "in flight" at once. In D3D11, you usually don't need to be concerned with this behavior though, and in fact it's intentionally difficult to introduce race conditions in the API. For example, when you call `Present`, the GPU will automatically flush all rendering, wait for all calls affecting the swap chain to complete, and present the correct image to the window.

In summary - no, D3D does not wait for the vertex/pixel shader operations to complete before returning from `Draw` calls, but usually you can ignore this fact.

Comment: Of course in Direct3D 12, synchronization is explicit so you the application coder have to insert fences and check their status to ensure it is safe to destroy referenced resources.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation , it helped.